# How can I send a response from Web API to an angular resource query?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Angular query.

```
services.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users', {

    }, {
        query: { method: 'GET' }
    });
});
```

and

```
$scope.searchedUsers = UserFactory.query({ searchString: "test" });
```

From Asp.Net Web Api, I'm returning

```
return Request.CreateResponse<List<User>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, users);
```

Then Angular throws the error

> Response does not match configured parameter Error in resource
>   configuration for action `object`. Expected response to contain an
>   array but got an {2} (Request: {3} {4})

But when I look at the response in developer tools, it appears to be an array:

```
[{"Id":0,"name":"test"},{"Id":0,"name":"test"}]
```

Why is it throwing this error?

Comment: have you tried setting your factory to this:
query: { method: 'GET',isArray:true}

Comment: @Dylan Yes, that works! Thank you! Make that an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: No problem. Changed my answer

Comment: Is it necessary that you implement a "query" method on the $resource object? With the isArray now set to true, you are mimicking the default $resource api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your factory to

```
query: { method: 'GET',isArray:true}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm stuck using Web Api 1, so IHttpActionResult doesn't exist.